# How to apply recursion over this problem and solve this problem

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, recursion, generator

The Problem is:-

```
Given a digit string, return all possible letter combinations of each digits according to the buttons on a telephone, that the number could represent.
The returned strings must be lexicographically sorted.

Example-1 :-
Input : “23”  
Output : ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf"]   

Example-2 :-
Input : “9”
Output: [“w”, “x”, “y”, “z”]

Example-3 :-
Input : “246”
Output : ["agm", "agn", "ago", "ahm", ..., "cho", "cim", "cin" "cio"] {27 elements}
```

I've squeezed my brain on this, and I've tried a lot but I'm not getting ahead of this part, what I've tried is to use a recursive function that zips the individual letters of each digit with each other letters and use `itertools.combinations()` over it, but I'm unable to complete this function and I'm unable to get ahead of this.

What I've tried is :-

```py
times, str_res = 0, ""

def getval(lst, times):
    if times==len(lst)-1:
        for i in lst[times]:
            yield i
    else:
        for i in lst[times]:
            yield i + getval(lst, times+1)

dct = {"2":("a","b","c"), "3":("d","e","f"), "4":("g","h","i"),
     "5":("j","k","l"), "6":("m","n","o"), "7":("p","q","r","s"),
     "8":("t","u","v"), "9":("w","x","y","z"), "1":("")}

str1, res = "23", []

if len(str1)==1:
    print(dct[str1[0]])
else:
    temp = [dct[i] for i in str1]
    str_res = getval(temp, times)
    print(str_res)
```

Please suggest me your ideas over this problem or in completing the function...

Comment: It's not itertools.combinations that you want, it's itertools.product

Comment: `from itertools import product; s = '23'; print( list(''.join(p) for p in product(*(dct[c] for c in s))) )` will print
`['ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not itertools.combinations that you need, it's [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```py
from itertools import product

def all_letter_comb(s, dct):
    for p in product(*map(dct.get, s)):
        yield ''.join(p)

dct = {"2":("a","b","c"), "3":("d","e","f"), "4":("g","h","i"),
     "5":("j","k","l"), "6":("m","n","o"), "7":("p","q","r","s"),
     "8":("t","u","v"), "9":("w","x","y","z"), "1":("")}

for s in ['23', '9', '246']:
    print(s)
    print(list(all_letter_comb(s, dct)))
    print()
```

Output:

```
23
['ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf']

9
['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

246
['agm', 'agn', 'ago', 'ahm', 'ahn', 'aho', 'aim', 'ain', 'aio', 'bgm', 'bgn', 'bgo', 'bhm', 'bhn', 'bho', 'bim', 'bin', 'bio', 'cgm', 'cgn', 'cgo', 'chm', 'chn', 'cho', 'cim', 'cin', 'cio']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong this is leet code problem. You can find multiple answers there.